# LibreOffice SDK read formula result

Tags: java, sdk, libreoffice-calc

I am using the LibreOffice SDK to create a Java program that reads data from a Calc spreadsheet.  One of the cells has a formula in it that returns text (i.e. **not** a numeric/double value).

XCell.getFormula() returns the actual formula ("=I6"), rather than the result ("my text").

I have looked at the LibreOffice SDK API, and it appears that XCell.getValue() will return the formula result, *as long as it is a number*.  There does not appear to be any other methods to return formula results.

I have tried to set the cell type from Number to Text, using getFormula() and getValue().  Neither of these work.

Is there a way to get the textual result of a formula using the LibreOffice SDK?

Many thanks

Fintan

Comment: `String sString = XCell`[**.getString();**](http://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/text/XTextRange.html#getString)?

Comment: @JohnSUN Nice try!  There is no XCell.getString() method, nor an XCell.getFormulaResult() method.  Both of which would make sense.  Will try your other solution now.  Thans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try so

```
        XCell xCell = xCellRangesAccess.getCellByPosition(....);
        XTextRange xTextRange = UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XTextRange.class, xCell);
        String sString = xTextRange.getString();
```